# Scope and Asynchronous JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope

I recently ran into an issue at work in which, at least according to my knowledge of JavaScript, I got back an impossible result.  I'm hoping someone can explain whats going on here and why the actual results differ from my expected results.

#### Expected results in console

```
id: a , x: 1
id: b , x: 1
id: c , x: 1
```

#### Actual results in console

```
id: c , x: 1
id: c , x: 2
id: c , x: 3
```

#### Code

```
function MyClass(id)
{
    var x = 0;

    return function()
    {
        return function()
        {
            x += 1;
            console.log("id: ", id, ", x: ", x);
        }
    }
}


function DoStuff(id)
{
    var q = MyClass(id);
    response_callback = q();
    setTimeout(function(){ response_callback(); }, 50);
}

DoStuff("a");
DoStuff("b");
DoStuff("c");
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ response_callback(); }, 50);` can be replaced with `setTimeout(response_callback, 50)`

Comment: @Dan, well it *can* be, but then you won't get devious bugs, even without the `var`...

Comment: @Matthew: that sounds like it's the intention to get devious bugs. ;)

Comment: +1 well written question that sheds interesting light on an easy error to miss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> response_callback = q();
> ```

This. You didn't declare *response_callback* in any scope, so it's implicitly in the global scope...

Which means you're overwriting it every time you call `DoStuff()`. You *think* you're getting three different functions captured and called, but there's only one...

```
 var response_callback = q(); // should set you back on track
```

Of course, the way you have this structured right now kinda wastes `MyClass`'s ability to return a function that returns a function. You could actually write:

```
function DoStuff(id)
{
  var q = MyClass(id);
  // ... do other strange and horrible things with q ...
  setTimeout(q(), 50);
}
```

...and see the same results without an unnecessary closure.

Comment: Thank you, its always the simple things that kill you.  Only excuse for missing this is that its crunch time, everyone here has been working 12 hour days for a while, and three sets of eyes didn't catch that.